# Retrieve serialized in Appengine JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

My table in my appengine app has a field called "fields".
this fields is a String[] in my Employee persistence object

```
@Persistent
@Serialized
private String[] fields;
```

The user search for multiple fields (i.e field1,field2 etc')
and i want to search for objects has in their fields at least one of the user input fields.
How i do that with JDO?

Answer (score 0):

You've serialised them, so they aren't searchable by query. Retrieve the Employee objects and check them one by one. Alternatively don't serialise the field (assuming GAE supports query of "field.contains(value)")